# Container View in Storyboard isn't allowed make more than one segue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, container-view

[image]
I try to add more children for Container view but prevent me and only make one segue.

Comment: This is not a real question. Stackoverflow isn't a 'write my code' site. You have to show us your effort. You should read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the connections from the view controller instead from a subview.

Comment: This mean make the connection with view controller not with container view , Do you mean this ?

Comment: Still only allow to make one segue please i have update question with new screen